# Combining a rvest scraping loop's outcome into a dataframe

Tags: r

All,

I am trying to scrape some information from the web using rvest by looping through a list of webpages and then combine the results from all pages into a dataframe (each page scrapped adding to a new row).

My full code is :

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

    ####### Cleaning Functions ######

na.zero <- function (x) {
x[is.na(x)] <-0
return(x)
}

#/ 

######### Team Scrapping Code ############

TeamScrape <- read_html("http://www.transfermarkt.com/jumplist/startseite/verein/2778")


#// Get Club Name

#ClubName <- TeamScrape %>%
#html_nodes(".spielername-profil") %>%
#html_text()

#// Get All Player URLs 

PlayerURLs <- TeamScrape %>%
html_nodes(".spielprofil_tooltip") %>%
html_attr("href")

PlayerURLs <- unique(PlayerURLs)
PlayerURLs <- na.omit(PlayerURLs)

PlayerURLs <- paste0("http://www.transfermarkt.com", PlayerURLs)

PlayerLinks = data.frame(PlayerURLs)


######### Player Scrapping Code ############

lapply(PlayerURLs, FUN=function(URLLink){
PlayerScrape <- read_html(URLLink)

Name <- PlayerScrape %>% 
  html_nodes(".spielername-profil") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()
  Name <-ifelse(length(nchar(Name)) !=0 , Name, 0)
Name <- gsub("\t", "", Name)
Name <- gsub("\r", "", Name)
Name <- gsub("\n", "", Name)

DOB <- PlayerScrape %>% 
  html_nodes(".wsnw > span:nth-child(1)") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()
  DOB <-ifelse(length(nchar(DOB)) !=0 , DOB, 0)
DOB <- gsub("\t", "", DOB)
DOB <- gsub("\r", "", DOB)
DOB <- gsub("\n", "", DOB)

Club <- PlayerScrape %>% 
  html_nodes(".vereinprofil_tooltip+ .vereinprofil_tooltip") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()
  Club <-ifelse(length(nchar(Club)) !=0 , Club, "-")

Nationality <- PlayerScrape %>% 
  html_nodes("#main .flaggenrahmen+ span") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()
  Nationality <-ifelse(length(nchar(Nationality)) !=0 , Nationality, "-")

SquadNo <- PlayerScrape %>% 
  html_nodes(".rueckennummer-profil") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()
  SquadNo <- gsub("#", "", SquadNo) %>%
  as.numeric()
  SquadNo <-ifelse(length(nchar(SquadNo)) !=0 , SquadNo, 0)

Age <- PlayerScrape %>% 
  html_nodes(".profilheader .hide-for-small td") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.numeric()
  Age <-ifelse(length(nchar(Age)) !=0 , Age, 0)

Position <- PlayerScrape %>% 
  html_nodes(".hauptposition-left") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()
  Position <-ifelse(length(nchar(Position)) !=0 , Position, "-")
Position <- gsub("\t", "", Position)
Position <- gsub("\r", "", Position)
Position <- gsub("\n ", "", Position)
Position <- gsub("Main position:", "", Position)
Position <- str_trim(Position, side = c("both"))

Height <- PlayerScrape %>% 
  html_nodes(".hide-for-small~ tr+ tr span") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()
  Height <- gsub(",", "", Height)
  Height <- gsub(" m", "", Height)
  Height <-ifelse(length(nchar(Height)) !=0 , Height, 0)

Apps <- PlayerScrape %>% 
  html_nodes(".hide.hide-for-small+ .zentriert") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.numeric()
  Apps <- na.zero(Apps)
  Apps <-ifelse(length(nchar(Apps)) !=0 , Apps, 0)

Goals <- PlayerScrape %>% 
  html_nodes("#yw1 tfoot .zentriert:nth-child(4)") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.numeric()
  #Goals <- na.zero(Goals)
  #if(is.null(Goals)){Goals <-0}
  Goals <-ifelse(length(nchar(Goals)) !=0 , Goals, 0)

Assists <- PlayerScrape %>% 
  html_nodes("tfoot .zentriert:nth-child(5)") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.numeric()
  Assists <- na.zero(Assists)
  Assists <-ifelse(length(nchar(Assists)) !=0 , Assists, 0)

Minutes <- PlayerScrape %>% 
  html_nodes("tfoot .zentriert:nth-child(7)") %>%
  html_text()
  Minutes <-ifelse(length(nchar(Minutes)) !=0 , Minutes, 0)

Value <- PlayerScrape %>%
  html_nodes(".marktwert a") %>%
  html_text()
  Value <-ifelse(length(nchar(Value)) !=0 , Value, "-")

ContractExp <- PlayerScrapprinte %>% 
  html_nodes(".profilheader tr:nth-child(6) td") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()
  ContractExp <-ifelse(length(nchar(ContractExp)) !=0 , ContractExp, "-")
ContractExp <- gsub("\t", "", ContractExp)
ContractExp <- gsub("\r", "", ContractExp)
ContractExp <- gsub("\n", "", ContractExp)

PlayerURLLink <- URLLink
ProfileID <- PlayerURLLink
ProfileID <- str_extract_all(ProfileID,"\\(?[0-9,]+\\)?")

Checker = data.frame(Name, Club, Nationality, Position, Height, SquadNo, Value, DOB, Age, Apps, Minutes, Goals, Assists, PlayerURLLink)

})
```

In the console I get the scraped data but its not combining into a dataframe with all records as new rows. All help and advice very appreciated!

```
              Name             Club Nationality Position Height
1 David Jensen FC Nordsjaelland     Denmark        -    195
  SquadNo     Value          DOB Age Apps Minutes Goals
1       1 500 Th. € Mar 25, 1992  23   18       0    27
  Assists
1       5
                                                   PlayerURLLink
1 http://www.transfermarkt.com/david-jensen/profil/spieler/78819

[[2]]
                  Name             Club Nationality Position
1 Rúnar Alex Rúnarsson FC Nordsjaelland     Iceland        -
  Height SquadNo     Value          DOB Age Apps Minutes
1      0      16 100 Th. € Feb 18, 1995  20    1       0
  Goals Assists
1     1       0
                                                            PlayerURLLink
1 http://www.transfermarkt.com/runar-alex-runarsson/profil/spieler/205657

[[3]]
                  Name                 Club Nationality
1 Peter Vindahl Jensen FC Nordsjaelland U19     Denmark
  Position Height SquadNo    Value          DOB Age Apps
1        -      0       0 50 Th. € Feb 16, 1998  17    0
  Minutes Goals Assists
1       0     0       0
                                                            PlayerURLLink
1 http://www.transfermarkt.com/peter-vindahl-jensen/profil/spieler/395421

[[4]]
           Name             Club Nationality    Position
1 Pascal Gregor FC Nordsjaelland     Denmark Centre Back
  Height SquadNo     Value          DOB Age Apps Minutes
1      0       3 700 Th. € Feb 18, 1994  21   17   1.530
  Goals Assists
1    NA       0
```

Comment: thank! I changed that to URLLink which clears that issue and allows the function to run! The console is now displaying the output below, but it isn't combining into the checker dataframe. Any ideas?

Comment: [[1]]
          Name             Club Nationality Position Height
1 David Jensen FC Nordsjaelland     Denmark        -    195
  SquadNo     Value          DOB Age Apps Minutes Goals
1       1 500 Th. € Mar 25, 1992  23   18       0    27
  Assists
1       5
                                                   PlayerURLLink
1 http://www.transfermarkt.com/david-jensen/profil/spieler/78819

[[2]]
                  Name             Club Nationality Position
1 Rúnar Alex Rúnarsson FC Nordsjaelland     Iceland        -
  Height SquadNo     Value          DOB Age Apps Minutes
1      0      16 100 ETC

Comment: @tospig just done - thanks

Comment: actually, I think you just need to assign your `lapply` to a variable, such as `lst_scraped_data <- lapply(PlayerURLS, FUN=functin( ...){... }`. Then you can `df <- do.call(rbind, lst_scraped_data)` to get it into a `data.frame`

Comment: Because, your `lapply` is returning a **list**, but you're not assigning it to anything. This is why it's printing to the console.

Comment: you also have a typo : `ContractExp <- PlayerScrapprinte %>% ` should be `ContractExp <- PlayerScrape %>% `

Comment: Also,  why did this question get a down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the missing variable, your only real issue is that you're not assigning your `lapply` to anything, it's just printing to the console.

Using the construct

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

lst_scraped_data <- lapply(PlayerURLs, FUN=function(URLLink){

    ## --------------------------
    ## all the function code here
    ## --------------------------

}

df <- do.call(rbind, lst_scraped_data)
```

gives you your `data.frame`